# IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml];

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am developing my Second Web Application using

1. Spring Framework (Core, MVC & JDBC)
2. Java 1.8
3. Maven 3.3.9
4. Eclipse IDE (Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0))
5. MySQL 5.1.

Everything step was done as per the reference website, but getting the following error.  Please help in resolving the error.

Error Stacktrace at Tomcat Console:

```
[Sat Dec 28 16:39:59 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
28-Dec-2019 16:39:59.208 INFO [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]
28-Dec-2019 16:39:59.599 INFO [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml]
28-Dec-2019 16:39:59.602 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
        org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:jbr/config/user-beans.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:233)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
                at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1089)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4871)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:227)
                ... 67 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
                at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
                ... 71 more
28-Dec-2019 16:39:59.618 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [E:\work\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\webapps\userRegistrationAndLogin.war] has finished in [2,620] ms
28-Dec-2019 16:39:59.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [E:\work\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\webapps\adminapplication]
```

spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:jbr/config/user-beans.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="jbr.springmvc" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

user-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="jbr.springmvc" />
  <context:annotation-config />

  <bean id="userService" class="jbr.springmvc.service.UserServiceImpl" />
  <bean id="userDao" class="jbr.springmvc.dao.UserDaoImpl" />

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_mvc" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="ranjith" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

java-spring-mvc project hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. Posting a plain stacktrace is not very helpful. Also, the latter one clearly states what the problem is.

`nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jbr/config/user-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

How are you attempting to load the file in question.

Comment: Added the information as requested below the stack trace. Also shared the project hierarchy image link at the start of the question.

Comment: Does your .war file contain a `WEB-INF/classes/jbr/config/user-beans.xml` entry?  Does it contain a .jar under WEB-INF/lib with a `jbr/config/user-beans.xml` entry?